# how to read video file and split it into frames

Tags: android, opencv

I have this question: how can I load, in Android, a video file stored in my device, and how can I split it into frames? 
I'm using IntelliJ and I want to split the video into frames in order to process them with some image processing techniques (with OpenCv for Android library).

Answer (score 1):

You don't strictly need to use OpenCV for this. You can use the [MediaMetaDataRetreiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) class provided by the SDK. It provides methods to extract metadata from all kinds of media files. You can try something like:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

retriever.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());

imgView.setImageBitmap(retriever.getFrameAtTime(TIME_OFFSET,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST));
```

where `TIME_OFFSET` is in microseconds.

Comment: I will try also this solution. Thank you!

Comment: Too slow, each extraction of frame takes around 200-300 milli seconds

Comment: I've tried using MediaMetadataRetriever but i can't get the different frames repeatedly same frames for all images i've posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776177/how-can-we-get-frames-in-android see this can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Grabbing a video frame in OpenCV is pretty easy. There are lots of examples on OpenCV site. However crucial thing is to set-up opencv on andriod. You can follow this link on getting started with Opencv on andriod.

http://opencv.org/android

Once you have opencv installed on andriod. You can easily load video file and grab frame in Mat structure and then do some processing on it.

Here is the sample one. It will need some modification to run it on andriod. I think you will need to used NDK on andriod for this.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

    char *my_file = "C:\\vid_an2\\desp_me.avi";
    std::cout<<"Video File "<<my_file<<std::endl;
    cv::VideoCapture input_video;

    if(input_video.open(my_file))
    {
         std::cout<<"Video file open "<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Not able to Video file open "<<std::endl;

    }
    namedWindow("My_Win",1);
    namedWindow("Segemented", 1);
    Mat cap_img;
    for(;;)
    {
         input_video >> cap_img;
         imshow("My_Win", cap_img);
          waitKey(0);
    }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I have read something about ndk, and I have seen how to use it. But it is not clear to me how a cpp function (declared and defined in the cpp file) can return values to the java class,which is the owner of that native methods.

Comment: I don't think that VideoCapture will work in Android becuase OpenCV for Android doesn't have backend FFMpeg