# How can we get frames in Android

Tags: android, video, frame, android-sdcard

Actually i need to get all the frames from videos but I use to get first frame repeatedly then specific time frames while using Mediametadatareteriver,thumbnail,timestamp to get frames.

I'd tried a lot for fixing by changing all GetFrameAtTime(options) but remains the same.

my Duration of video is 127040(2:07sec) here i Splited as 32 frames and save frames in SDCard can view all 32 but repeatedly same frames for all 32 frames.

I should get these without the help of FFMPEG and xuggler.

Is there any alternatives methods or any other Library files for using in Android if there please help me Friends.

Here is my full code

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File videoFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Movies/MEMO.mp4";

        Uri videoFileUri=Uri.parse(videoFile.toString());

        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        ArrayList<Bitmap> rev=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();


        //Create a new Media Player
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), videoFileUri);
        int millis = mp.getDuration();
        for(int i=0;i<millis;i+=100){
           Bitmap bitmap=retriever.getFrameAtTime(i,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
           rev.add(bitmap);

          try {
              saveFrames(rev);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }



    public void saveFrames(ArrayList<Bitmap> saveBitmapList) throws IOException{

        String folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File saveFolder = new File(folder + "/Movies/new /";
        if(!saveFolder.exists()){
           saveFolder.mkdirs();
        }


        int i=1;
        for (Bitmap b : saveBitmapList){
           ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

            File f = new File(saveFolder,("frame"+i+".jpg");

            f.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream;
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

               fo.flush();
               fo.close();

            i++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) should solve your problem. A sample APK to test with can be found [here](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/blob/master/fmmr-demo/FMMRDemo.apk?raw=true). Just click on a file on your sdcard and you will be prompted to open it with the demo application.

To use the library simply untar the contents of [this](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/blob/master/fmmr-library/prebuilt-libs.tar.gz) file into your projects "libs" folder. and change your existing import statements from:

```
import android.media.MetadataRetriever;
```

to:

```
import wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever;
```

and change:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
```

to:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
```

Comment: Sir actually i'm new to android tried a lot to fix the issues using Mediametadatareteriver but no use.

Comment: Sir i'm new to Android can you guide me please should i include this FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever in Eclipse and is there any code to execute this method

Comment: The project I referred you to has a very detailed README, I suggest reading that. Regardless, I updated my answer.

Comment: Sir after importing the prebuilt.jar into my libs folder along with four content folder i got the error message as java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError mediaplayer not found for that i'd referred https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer/issues/1 to fix the issue but it remains the same can you give the solution to go ahead.

Comment: If your project is set up normally you shouldn't have an issue. You can file a bug report and/or email me using my contact information on github if you require more assistance.

Comment: @WilliamSeemann FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever also gives same frame

Comment: https://github.com/bhuvnesh123/FFmpeg-Video-Editor-Android
If someone reach here in search this project is helpful